# Sum pandas columns, excluding some rows based on other column values

Tags: pandas

I'm attempting to determine the number of widget failures from a test population.

Each widget can fail in 0, 1, or multiple ways. I'd like to calculate the number of failures of for each failure method, but once a widget is known to have failed, it should be excluded from future sums. In other words, the failure modes are known and ordered. If a widget fails via mode 1 and mode 3, I don't care about mode 3: I just want to count mode 1.

I have a dataframe with one row per item, and one column per failure mode. If the widget fails in that mode, the column value is 1, else it is 0.

```
d = {"item_1": 
         {"failure_1":0, "failure_2":0}, 
     "item_2":
         {"failure_1":1, "failure_2":0}, 
     "item_3":
         {"failure_1":0, "failure_2":1}, 
     "item_4":
         {"failure_1":1, "failure_2":1}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d).T
display(df)
```

Output:

```
        failure_1  failure_2
item_1          0          0
item_2          1          0
item_3          0          1
item_4          1          1
```

If I just want to sum the columns, that's easy: `df.sum()`. And if I want to calculate percentage failures, easy too: `df.sum()/len(df)`. But this counts widgets that fail in multiple ways, multiple times. For the problem stated, the best I can come up with is this:

```
# create empty df to store results
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["total_failures"])

for col in df.columns:
    # create a row, named after the column, and assign it the value of the sum
    df2.loc[col] = df[col].sum()

    # drop rows in the df column that are equal to 1
    df = df.loc[df[col] != 1]

display(df2)
```

Output:

```
          total_failures
failure_1              2
failure_2              1
```

This requires creating another dataframe (that's fine), but also requires iterating over the existing dataframe columns *and* deleting it a couple of rows at a time. If the dataframe takes a while to generate, or is needed for future calculations, this is not workable. I can deal with iterating over the columns.

Is there a way to do this without deleting the original df, or making a temporary copy? (Not workable with large data sets.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) on `axis=1` and wherever the value is greater than 1 , [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) it as `0` and then take sum:

```
out = df.mask(df.cumsum(axis=1).gt(1), 0).sum().to_frame('total_failures')
```

---

```
print(out)

           total_failures
failure_1               2
failure_2               1
```

This way the original `df` is retained too.